# I got an error in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2015, msbuild

The specified task executable "csc.exe" could not be run, load file or assembly

> 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Care to share a few more details?

Comment: [How do I ask a **good** question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Can you find the dll file in your project reference of the solution explorer window?
If possible, please open the package manager console window and install it manually:

Install-Package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp -Version 1.0.0

If still no help, please share the latest information(detailed error or warning and project type) and check your .NET Framework version and setup.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/1.0.0

This packages Supported Platforms:

- .NET Framework 4.5
- Windows 8
- Portable Class Libraries